# Get value outside php for loop

Tags: php

I am calling a file reading it's data line by line and then I want to echo it.
I have tried so far is.

```
$file = file("sitemap.dat");
    $count = count($file);
    $limit = $count;

for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++)
{

$chunk=$file[$i];
$chunk=str_replace('
','',$chunk);
$main = explode("---",$chunk);
$main[i] = $content;
$recent = '<li><a href="'.$main[0].'">'.$main[1].'</a></li>';
$vuzz = $recent;
}

$myamazingvar = '<h4>Recent entries to file</h4><div>'.$vuzz.'</div>';

$page = '<main>main</main><aside>'.$myamazingvar.'</aside>';

echo $page;
```

The problem is that it only outputs the last one in loop. But i want all entries in the file listed. as you can see limit = count. also how can i reverse this.

Comment: And i am surprised to see someone downvoted my question for no reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use that code

```
    var $content_main="";
    for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++)
    {

        $chunk=$file[$i];
        $chunk=str_replace('
        ','',$chunk);
        $main = explode("---",$chunk);
        $main[i] = $content;
        $recent = '<li><a href="'.$main[0].'">'.$main[1].'</a></li>';
        $vuzz = $recent;
        $content_main .= $vuzz;
    }
    $myamazingvar = '<h4>Recent entries to file</h4><div>'.$content_main.'</div>';
```

Comment: can i use array_reverse to reverse and get it listed reversed. (too much reverse :) )

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

```
  $file = file("sitemap.dat");
        $count = count($file);
        $limit = $count;
    $vuzz='';
    for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++)
    {

    $chunk=$file[$i];
    $chunk=str_replace('
    ','',$chunk);
    $main = explode("---",$chunk);
    $main[i] = $content;
   $vuzz. = '<li><a href="'.$main[0].'">'.$main[1].'</a></li>'; //Concat the data
    }

   $page = '<main>main</main><aside><h4>Recent entries to file</h4><div>'.$vuzz.'</div></aside>';

    echo $page;
```

Comment: `PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in your code on line 17
$vuzz. = $recent.'&nbsp; &nbsp;';`

Comment: Cool. It's not an issue. All the best :)